# Excel combine cells, exclude null, read dates correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wonder if anyone can help with this? I'm helping a client sort out years of badly named files (column A in Excel spreadsheet).

I'm generating filenames for multiple files using several parameters (source, author, topic etc) in columns B-G, then enter a relevant date in the H column.

I've tried 2 options:

Using this formula works but includes wrong values where columns are not completed
`=C29&""&D29&""&E29&""&F29&""&G29&""&TEXT(H29,"yymmdd")&""&I29`

e.g. `StaffMeetingNotesJB200421` (relates to example below)

Using this formula removes spaces where columns are not filled in, but trashes the date values:
`=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,C29:H29)`

e.g. `StaffMeetingNotesJB43942` (from example above)

How can I put this textifying code
`&TEXT(H29,"yymmdd")&`
into the TEXTJOIN formula that removes null values?

Or is there a better way?!

EDIT 1
Just tried this
`=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,C29:G29,TEXT(H29,"yymmdd"),I29)`
Which makes the date read OK but doesn't remove null cells

EDIT 2

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh5uC.png)

Comment: Do you have some sample data in a printscreen or maybe mockup markdown data?

Comment: Hi JvdV - thanks for responding. I've put a screenshot with examples and forumlae into the post. Interested to see if there's a solution. Thanks!